# Riddle to Code 2: The return of numbers

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, cipher, formation-of-numbers

> *The first is a pirates favorite letter*.
>   *The second is from a famous quote of shakespear*.
>   *The third is squaring it off in a famous formula*.
>   *The fourth is the first in a very well known song*.
>   *The fifth placed in a line from top to bottom makes the train go in the right direction*.
>   *The sixth in my language sounds like the fourth*.
>   *The seventh is what you thought was the answer on the first one*.
>   *The eight is is a mr from a famous team*.
>   *The ninth could be next to the first but is a bit more curvy*.

---

> Even Sherlock knows who *19326724815* is

Comment: Even though it is already answered, I encourage you to try to do it too, it's not that hard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first is a pirates favorite letter.

> **C** - A pirate's first love is "the sea"

The second is from a famous quote of Shakespeare.

> **B** - "To be or not to be..."

The third is squaring it off in a famous formula.

> **M** - $E=mc^2$ or perhaps $E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4$

The fourth is the first in a very well known song.

> **A** - the alphabet song?

The fifth placed in a line from top to bottom makes the train go in the right direction.

> **H** - If we put several together, it looks like a train track.

The sixth in my language sounds like the fourth.

> **E** - sounds like A (a bit)

The seventh is what you thought was the answer on the first one.

> **R** as in "aaarrrr".

The eight is is a mr from a famous team.

> **T** - Mr. T from the A-Team

The ninth could be next to the first but is a bit more curvy.

> **U** - Next to "C" in curvy, almost a bit more curved than C.

Even Sherlock knows who 19326724815 is

> CUMBERBATCH

Comment: That was fast xD

Comment: I've learnt something today! Always thought the 3rd syllable started with a 'P'.